# Finding the implicit constraint in a question

Tags: systems-of-equations

I came across this question.

$$
a+b+c=11 \\
ab+bc+ca=25 \\
a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc=?
$$

While trying to solve this I ended up with $abc=0$ and further solving gave $a= \frac{11-\sqrt{21}}{2}$, $b= \frac{11+\sqrt{21}}{2}$ and $c=0$. But, I am unable to see how two equations in the three unknowns yields an unique solution. Is there an implicit constraint or are there other solutions I am failing to see?

EDIT:
My line of solution was as follows -

$$
\begin{align*}
a^2+b^2+c^2 &= (a+b+c)^2 - 2(ab+bc+ca) \\
&= 11*11 - 50 = 71 \\
(a+b+c)^3 &= a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3a(b^2+c^2)+3b(a^2+c^2)+3c(b^2+c^2) +3abs \\
&= a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3a(71 - a^2) + 3b(71 - b^2) + 3c(71 - c^2) + 3abc\\
11^3 &= -2 (a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + 3*71*(a+b+c) +3abc \\
2(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) - 3abc &= (71*3 - 11^2)*11 = 92*11
\end{align*}
$$

I then arrived at mcd's comment like this

$$
\begin{align*}
(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)&=a^3+b^3+c^3+ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ac(a+c)\\
71*11&=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc+11*25 \\
a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc&=46*11
\end{align*}
$$

Solving the two simultaneous equations in $a^3+b^3+c^3$ and $abc$, I got $abc=0$ and rest followed. But I feel I am making a mistake some where that is making me lose other solutions to the given two equations.

Comment: Are you sure you have the sign correct in the expression requiring evaluation? $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)\big((a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca) \big),$$ which can be evaluated with the given information, even though that doesn't uniquely determine $a, b, c$.

Comment: The error is in this line: $$(a+b+c)^3 = a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3a(b^2+c^2)+3b(a^2+c^2)+3c(b^2+c^2) +3abc, $$ which should read $$(a+b+c)^3 = a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3a(b^2+c^2)+3b(a^2+c^2)+3c(b^2+c^2) +6abc. $$ Then one of your two equations is twice the other.

Comment: What you have, is that $a, b, c$ are the roots of $x^3 - 11x^2 + 25x - 0 = 0 $. The Vieta's formulas give you a unique solution (up to reordering of the roots).

Comment: Thanks mcd for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Thanks Calvin for that construct. With everyone's answer it is clear abc does not have to be zero. So, the cubic is $x^3-11x^2+25x-d =0$. Where abc is taken as d. So, we can have different a,b,c for different choices of d now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to show that $b$ and $c$ can be expressed by $a$ with a quadratic equation. Let $d=- 3a^2 + 22a + 21$, then we either have
$$
b=\frac{11-a+\sqrt{d}}{2},\; c=\frac{11-a-\sqrt{d}}{2},
$$
or
$b$ and $c$ interchanged. So these $(a,b,c)$ with arbitrary $a$ are the solutions.

In both cases, of course, then the third equation has the same value, which is
$$
2(3a^3 - 33a^2 + 75a + 253).
$$
However, this value *will depend on $a$*.
For example, with $a=0$, we obtain $b$ and $c$ as in the post,
$$
b=\frac{11+\sqrt{21}}{2},\; c=\frac{11-\sqrt{21}}{2}
$$
and the third equation has the value $506$.

Comment: sorry, $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc$  really is constant, value 506. But $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3abc$  is not constant. I took  $ a = \frac{11 + \sqrt{138}}{3} \; , \; \;    b = \frac{11 - \sqrt{138}}{3} \; , \; \;  c = \frac{11  }{3} \; . \; \;  $  Then  $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3abc= \frac{4180}{9} \approx 464.44$

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you, I have rolled back my original answer ( I changed it because I was no longer sure which sign we have).

Answer (score 1):

$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc$  really is constant, value 506.

**But $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3abc$  is not constant.**

Note:  the equations say $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 71,$  and the intersection of this sphere with the plane $a+b+c = 11 $  is a circle.

I took  $$ a = \frac{11 + \sqrt{138}}{3} \; , \; \;    b = \frac{11 - \sqrt{138}}{3} \; , \; \;  c = \frac{11  }{3} \; . \; \;  $$  Then  $$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3abc= \frac{4180}{9} \approx 464.44$$

The two given equations say that **the collection of $(a,b,c)$ points lie in a circle with center at $(11,11,11) / 3 $** and a certain radius, which I kept getting wrong. I started over more simply, knowing that there was a point of the circle to be found by taking the multiple of $(1, -1,0)$ from the center $(11,11,11) / 3 ,$   because $(1, -1,0)$ and  $(1, 1,1)$  are perpendicular.   That worked. That's how I picked the $\sqrt{138}$ stuff.

Comment: Thanks Will. This is very clear and gives an intuitive picture of the different possible solutions of the problem.

Comment: Hi Will ! Have a happy year 2024. I have much appreciated the 12 fingers joke (once more, too few humor in this site)...

Comment: @JeanMarie  Hello, and Happy New Year! Thanks for your kind words.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT(**very pertinent**).

One has $$(a+b+c)^3=a^3+b^3+c^3+6abc+3[+a(b^2+c^2)+b(a^2+c^2)+c(a^2+b^2)]\\(a+b+c)^3=a^3+b^3+c^3+6abc+3[ab(11-c)+ac(11-b)+bc(11-a)]\\(a+b+c)^3=a^3+b^3+c^3+6abc+3[11(ab+ac+bc)-3abc]\\(a+b+c)^3=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc+3\cdot11\cdot25$$ Finally we have
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=11^3-3\cdot11\cdot25=506$$ and **this value is not dependent of a free choice of $a$.**

But also has been shown above, choosing $a=0$, that $$a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc=506$$

The two first equations form a system which have no integer solutions but a quadratic one with a parameter (it could be any of $a,b,c$).

What I want to highlight is that  Discretizer said in his post about $abc=0$ seems not to be a mistake as he believed. The question remains when $a$ is not choosen equal to zero in Dietrich Burde's answer.

Answer (score 0):

$x^3-e_1x^2+e_2x-e_3=0$
$e_1=a+b+c=11$
$e_2=ab+bc+ca=25\\
e_3=abc$

By Newton-Girard identities,
$p_3=e_1^3-3e_1e_2+3e_3$

Hence,
$p_3-3e_3=e_1(e_1^2-3e_2)=11\times46=506$

I don't think that $p_3+3e_3$ is a constant.